# How does a possible strategy look like after the COVID-19 outbreak is under control?

Tags: covid-19, epidemiology

After several month of fighting against a nation wide epidemic China seems to have the spreading of SARS-CoV-2 under control assuming the official numbers are correct.
While the rest of the world is currently following China's lead with a delay of about two month the question arises how the future strategy against covid-19 could look like.

Is the only way to deal with this disease a vaccination whose development might take month, if not years?
A quarantine of a complete nation for several month is hardly conceivable. On the other hand there are only about 80.000 Chinese people who have developed resistances up to now and, therefore, a new spread is predictable as soon as the "social distancing" is canceled again.

Are there any strategies or techniques which have worked in comparable cases?

The only thing I could come up with is like the scenario depicted by braxlan:
[Would controlled infections with SARS-CoV-2/covid-19 help to protect the vulnerable part of the human population?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21437/would-controlled-infections-with-sars-cov-2-covid-19-help-to-protect-the-vulnera)

**Update**:
I found a [publication](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/medicine/sph/ide/gida-fellowships/Imperial-College-COVID19-NPI-modelling-16-03-2020.pdf) from the *Imperial College COVID-19 Response Team* where they "show  that intermittent  social  distancing –triggered  by  trends  in  disease  surveillance –may allow  interventions  to  be  relaxed  temporarily in relative  short  time  windows,  but  measures  will  need  to  be  reintroduced  if  or  when  case  numbers rebound."

[image: Illustration of adaptive triggering of suppression strategies]

Answer (score 0):

China fears a second wave of epidemic introduced from outside the country and so is tightly controlling its borders.  Since calculations show that with a R0 of 2.2, nearly 60% of the population needs to get infected for herd immunity to occur and that is not possible with a population of 1.4billion people.

The rational approach is to control the borders and wait for a vaccine.

https://www.forbes.com/sites/kenrapoza/2020/03/17/fear-of-a-second-coronavirus-outbreak-china-gets-tougher-on-foreign-travelers/#3ce231bc397e